# NULL value for attributes in Parcelable object. why?

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-intent, parcelable

I have the following `Recipe` class , which is implementing `Parcelable` class. But when I pass the object from one class to another the value of its attributes is `null`. why?

Recipe Class:

```
package mobile.bh.classes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import mobile.bh.activities.MethodStep;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

//simple class that just has one member property as an example
public class Recipe implements Parcelable {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;
    public ArrayList<MethodStep> method;
    public String comment;
    public String image;
    public Bitmap image2;

    public Recipe(){}
    /* everything below here is for implementing Parcelable */

    // 99.9% of the time you can just ignore this
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(name);
        out.writeList(ingredients);
        out.writeList(method);
        out.writeString(comment);
        out.writeString(image);
    }

    // this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Recipe> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Recipe>() {
        public Recipe createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Recipe(in);
        }

        public Recipe[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Recipe[size];
        }
    };

    // example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
    private Recipe(Parcel in) {
        in.writeInt(id);
        in.writeString(name);
        in.writeList(ingredients);
        in.writeList(method);
        in.writeString(comment);
        in.writeString(image);
        }
}
```

sending the object though `intent`

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context,RecipeInfoActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("recipeObj", recipe);
```

receiving the object in the other side

```
Recipe p = (Recipe) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("recipeObj");
```

but the value of `p.name` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Parcelable Constructor you need to read back from the parcel.

```
private Recipe(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name =in.readString();
        ingredients = in.readList();
        method = in.readList();
        comment = in.readString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use readInt instead of writeInt in your constructor (etc for the other fields)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your constructor, it appears your trying to write to the parcel all of your properties, but as far as I can tell, they haven't been set yet; possibly you meant to read from the Parcel there? Now I'm not sure what this Parcel exactly is, but I'm thinking its some sort of Properties-like class? If so, Java is not pass-by-reference. Meaning just modifiying the value handed to your method will not modifiy the real Parcel's value, you must return your modified Parcel